# Home Server Build around Xeon X3440 CPU

Tags: motherboard, server

I am starting a home server build. I am on a tight budget and aiming for the most quiet and low power build. I managed to salvage an Intel Xeon X3440 Processor from an old server. It uses an intel LGA1156 socket. After a brief google search it seems that the only boards that support this processor are server grade boards. I am looking for a recommendation for a low cost server board that will support my processor.

Link for CPU: http://ark.intel.com/products/42928/Intel-Xeon-Processor-X3440-8M-Cache-2_53-GHz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use motherboard with [Intel® P55 Express Chipset](http://ark.intel.com/pl/products/42690/Intel-BD82P55-PCH) it is not listed in compatible devices list but people run this Xeon on this chipset without any problems.

I recommend to look for some used motherboards with this chipset on auction portal which you use in your country (or specify country where we should look for it).

I would recommend looking for motherboards like:

- [MSI P55-GD65](https://msi.com/Motherboard/P55GD65.html#hero-overview)
- [Gigabyte GA-P55-USB3](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3440#ov)
- [Asus P7P55D](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P7P55D/specifications/)

But you can always look for other motherboards with [Intel® P55 Express Chipset](http://ark.intel.com/pl/products/42690/Intel-BD82P55-PCH)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to put that CPU on eBay.

By the time you source the motherboard, memory, drives, case, etc. (not to mention the time to find the time required to source and assemble all the parts) you are going to be in for at least $500 or more.

Why not look for a workstation class machine like this [Dell on eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Dell-Precision-T3500-Xeon-X5670-2-93GHz-Hex-Core-12gb-1tb-DVD-RW-Win7-Pro-/231881992941?hash=item35fd3e6aed:g:wv8AAOSwDNdV2iKF)?

It has a newer Xenon CPU, is fully built and ready to go.  You can even further customize it to your hearts content and the asking price is $250.

I am not knocking system building by any means, I just found that unless you are building a custom gaming rig, there really is nothing more efficient and economical than getting a used server/workstation rather than trying to source EOL parts.

Comment: Please don't use comments for extended discussion; take it to chat. @ZacAustin, if there are additional things you want to do with this that aren't mentioned in the question, please edit them in.